# Open source tools to automate QT application which is running on Windows, OSX, IOS,Android and Chrome Extension

Tags: windows, android, ios, chrome, qt

I am trying to automate an Instant Messenger application built on VoIP technology. Its available in all platforms (Windows, OSX, Android, IOS and as Chrome extension).

All these apps are developed using QT framework except chrome extension which was built using native chrome app JS.
Kindly suggest some nice open source as well as paid tool which suits all our needs.

Its not necessary a single Automation framework to support all needs, we are ready to integrate multiple frameworks to fulfill our requirement.Like Robot framework for ATDD + squish for QT integration, QTP + See test.

Please list down some open source as well as paid tools especially for Chrome browser extension automation

P.S. The tool is as similar as Skype. I cannot expose more details about the tool as its proprietary.

Comment: *business communicator application*? Please [edit] your question and be specific. What kind of automation tools do you need, what does it have to be capable of? What are you willing to pay for it? And not that question "How to get X to work"are off-topic here, you can only ask for software recommendations.

Comment: The tool is as similar as x-lite SIP phone. Its available in all platforms OSX, Windows, Android, IOS and Chrome extension. I am ready to pay for it but needs a best tool. Application was built using QT framework

Comment: I asked you to [edit] your question. Comments disappear. And you have not anwered all questions. *It is in your interest* to ask good questions

Comment: You can take a look at funq (open source tool): https://github.com/parkouss/funq But QT apps will definitely require some commercial automation software like Squash or TestComplete.

Comment: Thanks @VasilyRyabov Is there any alternative to squish available ? Any other open source framework available ? We are ready to integrate multiple frameworks like selenium + auto it. Please provide your suggestions. Is there any automation tool available to automate chrome extension (same skype kinda app) ? I have tried pywinauto too, swapy is not detecting chrome extension :(

Comment: Chrome automation needs UIA support (UIA is Microsoft Windows UI Automation API) that we plan to support in pywinauto as a back-end. Currently there are UIA extensions in AutoIt, RAutomation (on Ruby), TestStack.White (on C#) and maybe some other tools. The following list of tools might be useful: https://github.com/atinfo/awesome-test-automation

Comment: For QT automation I don't know any open source tools except "funq" I mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VasilyRyabov for your best suggesions